# Sql-statement with variables in python

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to execute a sql-statement via python. But this doesn't work:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE setting set foo=%s WHERE bar=%s", 4, str(sys.argv[1]))
```

This also doesn't work:

```
t = ("4",sys.argv[1])
cursor.execute('UPDATE setting set foo=? WHERE bar=?', t)
```

But this one works:

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE setting set foo=%s WHERE bar="something"', 3)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any details on the error message?   What does sys.argv[1] equal before you insert it in the SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE setting set foo=%s WHERE bar=%s", (4, str(sys.argv[1])))
```

The arguments need to be passed as a tuple if there are more than one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass the parameters as a tuple, even if there is only one:

```
cur.execute("insert into people values (?, ?)", (who, age))
```

Or:

```
cur.execute("insert into people values (?, 100)", (who,))
```